# WP7 MediaHistory.Instance null reference exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, instance, nullreferenceexception

Following the [instruction on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) about how to integrate my application with Music & Video Hub, I want to set the now playing tile and history tile.

Each time I receive `TrackEnded` event, which mean track is OK, I then set the Now playing tile in the Hub

However, I sometimes receive **null reference exception** on `MediaHistory.Instance`

```
MediaHistoryItem nowPlayingItem = new MediaHistoryItem();
nowPlayingItem.Title = track.Title;
nowPlayingItem.PlayerContext.Add("LaunchNowPlaying", myID);
nowPlayingItem.ImageStream = imageStream;
nowPlayingItem.Source = string.Empty;
MediaHistory.Instance.NowPlaying = nowPlayingItem; // null reference exception
```

Why and how to fix this ?

Comment: @RichardSzalay No. My workaround is to use try catch